# Disable tmux status left highlighting

Tags: tmux

My tmux config is almost totally how I want it, but for some reason my status left background keeps getting turned red/green after running for some time. I'd really like to get rid of this if possible.

Here's an image of what happens:
[image]

Here's a subset of my .tmux.conf that would be relevant. `colour226` is my yellow and `colour16` is my black:

```
# colors
set -g status-fg colour226
set -g status-bg colour16
set -g pane-active-border-fg colour226
set -g pane-active-border-bg colour226
set -g message-fg colour226
set -g message-bg colour16
set -g message-attr bright

# status bar
set -g window-status-current-bg colour226
set -g window-status-current-fg colour16
set -g window-status-current-attr bright
set -g window-status-current-format "#I:#W"
set -g window-status-format "#I:#W"
set -g window-status-style fg=green

set -g status-left-length 40
set -g status-left-style bg=colour16
set -g status-left "[#W]"
set -g status-left-attr bright

set -g status-right "%d %b %R"

set -g status-interval 60
set -g status-justify centre
setw -g monitor-activity on
```

You can see that I've tried forcing the status-left background to be black, but I think the activity monitor is causing it to show there.

I've been looking through the man page, but haven't found anything. Any ideas of how I might be able to disable the highlight?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, it is the "monitor-activity" that does that. Why don't you just set that off ? (that's what I do, for the same reason)